# Native Android OAuth2 authorization app instead of WebView for third party applications

Tags: android, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

TL;DR: I would like a native (already logged in) Android application provide auth tokens to third party applications installed on same device. I would like to use as much as possible of standard spring-security-oauth2 code as I am no OAuth2 expert.

Long version:

I have a system consisting of:

- an Android client application
- a central web application exposing some data via REST APIs currently secured by HTTP BASIC. The central app holds a repository of user accounts.

this all works well in an isolated environment.

Turns out third party Android app providers would like to integrate with my system. Actualy no REST API calls will be made - the only purpose of the integration is joined user accounts.

I have created an OAuth2 (spring security based) authentication server that third party apps can use - this way the users can use same credentials both in mine and third party apps.

Thing is: my users still have to enter the credentials at least once for each app. This is cumbersome: my users are kids - they often do not remember or are simply not able to input credentials.

Instead of forcing third party providers embed WebView in their application and handling OAuth2 calls to my server I would like them to call my application which is conveniently already logged in. My app would handle the actual authorization UI (via native activities) and respond back to calling app with proper tokens.

The main problem is: I do not know how to start.

Can I force spring-security-oauth2 to use JSON only? I see that the most important authorization endpoints generate html on the fly.

Do I have to create my own endpoints handling this approach or any standard OAuth2 flow would do?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Did you find a solution to this?